# ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse - Get original URL from browser address bar

Tags: php, apache

I have created two websites( http://localhost/webone, http://localhost/webtwo).

Web two has URL like this: http://localhost/webtwo/webone (Use ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse)

If we go to above URL, that display contents of the **web one**.

Now If someone access web one, then I want to catch user access URL.(It could be
http://localhost/webone or http://localhost/webtwo/webone)

**My Issue is:**

If someone access web two from http://localhost/webtwo/webone URL. Then if I execute following code it returns http://localhost/webone.

```
$actual_link = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

But browser display URL is http://localhost/webtwo/webone. Can someone please suggest a way to catch http://localhost/webtwo/webone URL.

Comment: Do you use session to store path?

Comment: try `$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Not working

Comment: Are you using any frameworks that might interfere with the `REQUEST_URI` value? And you are using the Apache webserver I assume?

Comment: @chrki I don't use any framework and Yes I am using Apache web server (xampp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add your custom request header by using [RequestHeader](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#requestheader) directive to request headers list (right after `ProxyPass*`):

```
RequestHeader add X-REQUEST-URI "expr=%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}"
```

This way you will have a header named `HTTP_X_REQUEST_URI`, a holder of requested URI and is accessible via `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUEST_URI']`:

```
'HTTP_X_REQUEST_URI' => string 'localhost/webtwo/webone' (length=23)
```

Also there are some headers which are set by `mod_proxy` and you may find useful. From [apache.org](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers):

> When acting in a reverse-proxy mode (using the `ProxyPass` directive,
>   for example), `mod_proxy_http` adds several request headers in order to
>   pass information to the origin server. These headers are:
>
> **X-Forwarded-For** The IP address of the client.
>
> **X-Forwarded-Host** The original host requested by the client in the Host HTTP request header.
>
> **X-Forwarded-Server** The hostname of the proxy server.

Answer (score 2):

When you are behind a **Proxy**:

Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']` in place of `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`
Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']` and 
`$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_SERVER']`
 in place of `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`

http://php.net/manual/de/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: And to prevent forgery, check that `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is the IP of your actual Proxy. Also, the X-headers will contain more than one value if the original request already contained them. The last comma-separated value should be the one coming from the (trusted) proxy. [mod_proxy Reference](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#x-headers)

Answer (score 0):

ProxyPass adds `X-Forwarded-Host` header, which contains original host, and is accessible in php as `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST']`.

Your code can be something like this:

```
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'])) {
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
$actual_link = "http://" . $host . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```